# Adding to a value in a Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having a bit of trouble with my script. I made a simple form, and what I want it to do is that when a user inputs his name, and the name is already in the array... his karma score would go up by 5. However I'm struggling with the adding part, I cannot get that to work.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

<?php

$karma_score = array(   array("Userid" => 1, "NameID" => 'Doe', "Karma" => 45, "LastLogin" => "2012-08-30"),
                        array("Userid" => 2, "NameID" => 'Smith', "Karma" => 123, "LastLogin" => "2012-09-02"),
                        array("Userid" => 3, "NameID" => 'Chan', "Karma" => 1, "LastLogin" => "2011-12-23"),
                        array("Userid" => 4, "NameID" => 'Zee', "Karma" => 15, "LastLogin" => "2012-07-01"));

function printArray($a){
    echo '<table border="1px">';
    echo '<tr>';
        foreach(array_keys($a[0]) as $head){
            echo '<th>'.$head.'</th>';
        }
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach($a as $b) {
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$b['Userid'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$b['NameID'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$b['Karma'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$b['LastLogin'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}

function findInfo($a){
    $InputName = $_POST['name'];

    for($counter = 0; $counter < 4; $counter++){
        foreach($a as $b) {
            if ($b['NameID'] === $InputName){
                // I would assume here is where the calculation would be done...
            }
        }
    }
printArray($karma_score);
}

while(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    findInfo($karma_score);
}

?>

<br>
<form action="" method="POST">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
ID: <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID #">
<input type="submit" name="submit">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code with my comments and suggestions:

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

<?php

// I am not sure why you have this variable here, But
// This variable will be initialized every time this page is loaded
// What it means is that this data won't be saved/updated for different users
// If you want data to keep updating across the web, you need to use a database
$karma_score = array(array("Userid" => 1, "NameID" => 'Doe', "Karma" => 45, "LastLogin" => "2012-08-30"),
    array("Userid" => 2, "NameID" => 'Smith', "Karma" => 123, "LastLogin" => "2012-09-02"),
    array("Userid" => 3, "NameID" => 'Chan', "Karma" => 1, "LastLogin" => "2011-12-23"),
    array("Userid" => 4, "NameID" => 'Zee', "Karma" => 15, "LastLogin" => "2012-07-01"));

function printArray($a)
{
    echo '<table border="1px">';
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach (array_keys($a[0]) as $head) {
        echo '<th>' . $head . '</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach ($a as $b) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $b['Userid'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $b['NameID'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $b['Karma'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $b['LastLogin'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}

// It seems like you are always passing
// $karma_score in here. If you want the original
// variable to always be updated, you need to pass
// it by reference like so:
// function findInfo(&$a)
function findInfo($a)
{
    // In the last line of the function
    // you are printing the variable $karma_score
    // Since, it's the global variable, you cannot directly use
    // it in here. You need to pull it in the function like so:
    // global $karma_score;

    $InputName = $_POST['name'];

    for ($counter = 0; $counter < 4; $counter++) {
        foreach ($a as $b) {
            if ($b['NameID'] === $InputName) {
                // I would assume here is where the calculation would be done...
            }
        }
    }
    printArray($karma_score);
}
// This is an infinite loop
// It should be if instead of a while
while (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Since you already have $karma_score as a global variable
    // You don't need to pass it here
    findInfo($karma_score);
}

?>

<br>

<form action="" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
    ID: <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID #">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</body>

</html>
```

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

<?php

$karma_score = array(array("Userid" => 1, "NameID" => 'Doe', "Karma" => 45, "LastLogin" => "2012-08-30"),
    array("Userid" => 2, "NameID" => 'Smith', "Karma" => 123, "LastLogin" => "2012-09-02"),
    array("Userid" => 3, "NameID" => 'Chan', "Karma" => 1, "LastLogin" => "2011-12-23"),
    array("Userid" => 4, "NameID" => 'Zee', "Karma" => 15, "LastLogin" => "2012-07-01"));

function printArray($a)
{
    echo '<table border="1px">';
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach (array_keys($a[0]) as $head) {
        echo '<th>' . $head . '</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach ($a as $b) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $b['Userid'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $b['NameID'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $b['Karma'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $b['LastLogin'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}

function findInfo()
{
    global $karma_score;

    $InputName = $_POST['name'];

        foreach ($karma_score as $key => $b) {
            if ($b['NameID'] === $InputName) {
                $karma_score[$key]["Karma"] += 5;
            }
        }

    printArray($karma_score);
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    findInfo();
}

?>

<br>

<form action="" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
    ID: <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID #">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: After I make those changes.. I get a few warning messages: Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/kleyer/public_html/Lab3Part2Table.php on line 17 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/kleyer/public_html/Lab3Part2Table.php on line 17

Comment: Thank you for the updated post. I made the changes according to your comments and the addition works. However, it is running on an infinite loop. I assumed it was the while loop so I changed it to an If statement and problem solved. I appreciate the time and effort you put into your answer!